# fgets() retorna NULL al leer archivo de texto

Tags: c, fgets

Cuando intento leer mi `FILE fpTextFixed` (`fgets(line,sizeof(line),fpTextFixed)`), este me devulve `NULL`, pero estaba corroborando y mi archivo fue abierto y escrito correctamente. 
Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es escribir un archivo binario a partir de la lectura de un archivo de texto de longitud fija.

### Archivo `main.c`

```c
/**main.c**/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "protFileTxt.h"


int main()
{
FILE *fpData,
     *fpDataFixed,
     *fpDataVariable,
     *fpTextFixed,
     *fpTextVariable;
student reg;
char line[LINE],
     *aux;

printf("\t\t\t\t Test File txt!\n");

if(!openFile(&fpData,FileStudent,"r+b",!CON_SIN_MSJ))
{
    createFileEstudent();
    if(!openFile(&fpData,FileStudent,"r+b",CON_SIN_MSJ))
        return 0;
}
if(!openFile(&fpTextFixed,FILE_TEXT_FIXED,"r+t",!CON_SIN_MSJ))
{
    if(!openFile(&fpTextFixed,FILE_TEXT_FIXED,"w+t",CON_SIN_MSJ))
    {
        fclose(fpData);
        return 0;
    }
}
if(!openFile(&fpTextVariable,FILE_TEXT_VARIABLE,"r+t",!CON_SIN_MSJ))
{
    if(!openFile(&fpTextVariable,FILE_TEXT_VARIABLE,"w+t",CON_SIN_MSJ))
    {
        fclose(fpData);
        fclose(fpTextFixed);
        return 0;
    }
}

fread(&reg,1,sizeof(reg),fpData);
while(!feof(fpData))
{
    //Preguntar por %-*s
    fprintf(fpTextFixed,"%08ld%-51s%-51s%-7.2f\n",reg.dni,reg.name,reg.surName,reg.average);

    fprintf(fpTextVariable,"%ld|%-s|%-s|%.2f\n",reg.dni,reg.name,reg.surName,reg.average);

    fread(&reg,1,sizeof(reg),fpData);
}
if(!openFile(&fpDataFixed,FileStudentFixed,"r+b",!CON_SIN_MSJ))
{
    if(!openFile(&fpDataFixed,FileStudentFixed,"w+b",CON_SIN_MSJ))
    {
        fclose(fpData);
        fclose(fpTextFixed);
        fclose(fpTextVariable);
        return 0;
    }
}
if(!openFile(&fpDataVariable,FileStudentVariable,"r+b",!CON_SIN_MSJ))
{
    if(!openFile(&fpDataVariable,FileStudentVariable,"w+b",CON_SIN_MSJ))
    {
        fclose(fpData);
        fclose(fpTextFixed);
        fclose(fpTextVariable);
        fclose(fpDataFixed);
        return 0;
    }
}
while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),fpTextFixed))
{
    if(!(aux = strchr(line,'\n')))
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error - No se pudo procesar archivo %s", FILE_TEXT_FIXED);
        fclose(fpData);
        fclose(fpTextFixed);
        fclose(fpTextVariable);
        fclose(fpDataFixed);
        fclose(fpDataVariable);
        return 0;
    }
    *aux = '\0';

    //TODO: funcion para verificar los campos de los registros leidos por fgets

    /** promedio alumno **/
    aux -= AVERAGE;
    sscanf(aux,"%f",&reg.average);
    *aux = '\0';
    /** apellido alumno **/
    aux -= SURNAME;
    sscanf(aux,"%s",&reg.surName);
    *aux = '\0';
    /** nombre alumno **/
    aux -= NAME;
    sscanf(aux,"%s",&reg.name);
    *aux = '\0';
    /** dni alumno **/
    aux -= DNI;
    sscanf(aux,"%ld",&reg.dni);
    *aux = '\0';

    fwrite(line,1,sizeof(line),fpDataFixed);
}

fclose(fpData);
fclose(fpTextFixed);
fclose(fpTextVariable);
fclose(fpDataFixed);
fclose(fpDataVariable);

return 0;
}
```

### Archivo `funFileTxt.c`

```c
/**funFileTxt.c**/
#include <stdio.h>
#include "protFileTxt.h"

void createFileEstudent()
{
FILE *fp;
student reg[] = {{87143658L, "Allende","Miguel",7.50},
             {30589425L,"Brito","Claudio",8.00},
             {46558892L,"Cena","Marcelo",8.90},
             {79815612L,"Dominguez","Diego",6.89},
             {46868278L,"Franzoi","Maximiliano",4.36},
             {32589614L,"Herrera","Cristobal",7.50},
             {47896425L,"Merlo","Micaela",8.55},
             {98713469L,"Oviedo","Cesar",6.00},
             {16887451L,"Pagnutti","Jose",8.98},
             {91649487L,"Perez","Leandro",7.39},
             {81659417L,"Recalde","Jose",7.28},
             {87952123L,"Recalde","Camila",5.56},
             {32139745L,"Rodriguez","Fabiana",7.00},
             {97962146L,"Romero","Johana",8.78},
             {34562501L,"Solla","Tamara",7.29},
             {16549654L,"Sosa","Federico",4.89},
             {66547893L,"Spinelli","Ezequiel",6.78},
             {21656154L,"Tapia","Jorge",8.56},
             {54514964L,"Torres","Mario",7.89},
             {22366985L,"Vizzoni","Daniela",6.56}};

fp = fopen(FileStudent,"wb");
if(fp)
{
    fwrite(reg,1,sizeof(reg),fp);
}
fclose(fp);
}


int openFile(FILE **file,const char *nameFile,const char *mode,int CON_SIN)
{
*file = fopen(nameFile,mode);

if(!*file)
{
    if(CON_SIN)
        fprintf(stderr,"Error - No se pudo abrir el archivo %s en modo %s",nameFile,mode);
    return 0;
}
return 1;
}
```

### Archivo `protFileTxt.h`

```c
/**protFileTxt.h**/
#define FileStudent "Data"
#define FileStudentFixed "DataFixed"
#define FileStudentVariable "DataVariable"
#define FILE_TEXT_FIXED "txtFixed"
#define FILE_TEXT_VARIABLE "txtVariable"
#define CON_SIN_MSJ 1
#define AVERAGE 9
#define SURNAME 51
#define NAME 51
#define DNI 8
#define LINE AVERAGE + SURNAME + NAME + DNI

typedef struct
{
long dni;
char name[51],
     surName[51];
float average;
}student;

int openFile(FILE **file,const char *nameFile,const char *mode,int CON_SIN);
void createFileEstudent();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Cuando haces `fgets` el indicador de posición del fichero se encuentra al final. Para devolverlo al principio usa [`rewind`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rewind)

En esta línea se abre el fichero usando `"r+t"`.

```
if(!openFile(&fpTextFixed,FILE_TEXT_FIXED,"r+t",!CON_SIN_MSJ))
```

En esta linea escribes al final del fichero :

```
//Preguntar por %-*s
fprintf(fpTextFixed,"%08ld%-51s%-51s%-7.2f\n",reg.dni,reg.name,reg.surName,reg.average);
```

Y cuando llegas al `fgets` la posición del fichero está al final, por lo que devuelve NULL. Si usas rewind empezará a leer desde el principio, con lo cual leerá lo que acabas de escribir.

```
rewind( fpTextFixed );
while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),fpTextFixed))
```

Una solución alternativa sería cerrar el fichero después de escribir y abrirlo antes de leer.

Answer (score 2):

El archivo `fpTextFixed` estuvo grabándose con:

```c
while(!feof(fpData))
{
    //Preguntar por %-*s
    fprintf(fpTextFixed,"%08ld%-51s%-51s%-7.2f\n",reg.dni,reg.name,reg.surName,reg.average);

    fprintf(fpTextVariable,"%ld|%-s|%-s|%.2f\n",reg.dni,reg.name,reg.surName,reg.average);

    fread(&reg,1,sizeof(reg),fpData);
}
```

Por lo tanto, el cursor se encuentra al final del archivo, y si se intenta leer con `fgets()`, retornará `NULL`. Para que esto no suceda, se debe rebobinar antes de realizar las lecturas:

```c
rewind(fpTextFixed);
```

Con la función `rewind()` le decimos a **c** que mande el cursor al principio del archivo, para poder leer los datos:

```c
while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),fpTextFixed))
{
    // ...
}
```